Profile User ID 195420 does not appear in query result for Blender Stack Exchange users
I'm trying to query out potential profile spam on Blender Stack Exchange using the following query on https://data.stackexchange.com/blender/query/new. It's not perfect since I'm still just testing out this Stack Exchange feature:

This is the query:
SELECT u.Id AS [UserId], u.DisplayName, u.Reputation, u.WebsiteUrl, u.AboutMe, u.Location
FROM Users u
WHERE u.WebsiteUrl != ''
AND u.AboutMe LIKE '%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%'
AND u.Reputation = 1
AND u.Location != ''
AND u.DisplayName LIKE '% %'  -- Checks if there is at least one space in the DisplayName
GROUP BY u.Id, u.DisplayName, u.Reputation, u.WebsiteUrl, u.AboutMe, u.Location

But I noticed that some profiles don't show up in the query result like this profile with User ID 195420 (I hope nobody edits it just yet)

Here's the query result. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT/UPDATE Just to give some context:

Thanks to @Thomas Owens's answer. So I guess the only way to
parse out profile spam on a daily basis is to use client side
JavaScript scraping? No other solution?
I want to use these results to populate a Profile Spam Detector
chrome extension in real time, check maybe every 5 minutes and
populate the list. In this list I can easily click the profile and
manage/delete it. This is what I have so far using JavaScript scraping
the new users page
1.
I'm looking into UserStalker to see if perhaps it's a potential
solution to send notification to the chrome extension.



Why not via the Users screen, sorted by CreationDate? On small-ish site like Blender, there are around 2-3 pages for a day, so if you check it daily, should be easy to spot spammers based on name or avatar. Not ideal, but think it's better than scraping.

@ShadowWizard yes currently I'm using javascript to fetch this url and scrape the data. But I was hoping to use some query from some SE API instead of javascript. I made a chrome extension where the spammers will just popup in this app to make it easier. But yes it's a small site and you could easily identify these users. But as the site grows this method will not be feasible anymore.

SEDE isn't real-time. The account was created today. SEDE was last updated about 5 days ago. The account will show up in the next synchronization between SEDE and the sites.

Hello thank you for the quick response! Oh nooo so that means there is no way for me to filter out profile spam but just via javascript then on client side scraping? :(

@HarryMcKenzie You could use the API. I would probably recommend that over scraping. But SEDE is only updated weekly, so if you want anything close to real-time, you'll have to use something else.

Sorry I'm confused.. As I understand it's impossible to get real-time data via the API. Just close-to-real-time is possible. Right? The only real-time I could possibly get is thru fetching this url and then parsing it via JavaScript. Or am I wrong? When you say API and SEDE what exactly is this API page you mean? But this API page is not real-time but just close-to-real-time right?

@HarryMcKenzie The Stack Exchange API. You do have to query it, but an API key gets 10,000 daily requests and up to 30 requests per second. You can query the /users endpoint, perhaps with some filters, to get some or all of the users on a site.

Thank you for sharing really appreciated :)

@HarryMcKenzie you know we have UserStalker, right? Ping me in the TL or drag me into a room if you want to talk.

@rene thank you for sharing! I'm trying to create a profile spam detector chrome extension which currently "works" very simple detection like this that stalks these profiles. Which I can easily click open the extension and see a list of detected spam. And each item listed can easily be clicked to manage/delete profile. With UserStalker this probably won't work as it is only for the command line and can't send notifications to the browser?

@rene thanks for letting me invite you to https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/1761/userstalker
